# Issues with Tensorflow and Python 3.6 using Pycharm on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

Installing tensorflow using pycharms interpreter package tools seized up my laptop before leaving me with a message saying there was an issue installing tensorflow. I restarted pycharm and tried reinstalling the package, it sorta seized up my laptop again but it said everything installed fine this time round. Now Im getting the following issue with my code:

```
/home/clay/PycharmProjects/ganymede/venv/bin/python /home/clay/PycharmProjects/ganymede/main.py
2020-04-01 22:07:09.176637: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-04-01 22:07:09.176781: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-04-01 22:07:09.176798: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/clay/PycharmProjects/ganymede/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "/home/clay/PycharmProjects/ganymede/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "/home/clay/PycharmProjects/ganymede/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .variables import variable
  File "/home/clay/PycharmProjects/ganymede/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

How do I even begin to solve this issue? I've only played around with python stuff for a little while now, I only have 'import' and 'print' written in my code so far ... ay caraba

Answer (score 1):

in the bottom of the pycharm IDE there's a tab called 'Terminal'.
click it and go to your python env :

```
/home/clay/PycharmProjects/ganymede/venv
```

in your case.

then type

```
python -m pip uninstall tensorflow
python -q pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```

if you don't see an output you successfully installed tensorflow
but if you do see something
delete tensorflow once again and try using a conda venv instead (tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIB7IZFCE_k)
then activate your venv and

```
conda install tensorflow
```

lastly. make sure your pycharm interpreter is ran on your conda venv.